# Why Brownie Test Class has no access to imported variables?

Tags: pytest, brownie

I'm writting a Brownie test like below:

```
from brownie import accounts

class Test1:
    my_account = accounts\[0\]

    def test_fn:
        ...
```

The test result says "my_account = accounts[0], list index out of range"

But if I put "my_account = accounts[0]" inside test_fn like below, then the test runs fine.

```
from brownie import accounts

class Test1:

    def test_fn:
        my_account = accounts\[0\]
        ...
```

Why is that? what's the pytest scope for imported variables?

Tried searching anything related to pytest variable scope, but none suit my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can not reproduce your example because I do not have any accounts in both cases.
However, I think your issue is happening because this `accounts` variable must be filled with values according to [account management page](https://eth-brownie.readthedocs.io/en/stable/account-management.html) in brownie's docs.

Class properties definition is executed during collection stage. Tests are executed after collection stage is finished. So if `accounts` in your case are filled somewhere else in code (e.g. in autouse fixture or other test) it will not be accessible during pytest's collection stage.

May be you can provide some more details about your case. How are you generating this accounts in your successful case?

UPD:

According to `eth-brownie` package source code using `brownie test` is executing `pytest` with enabled `pytest-brownie` plugin like this:

```
pytest.main(pytest_args, ["pytest-brownie"])
```

So this plugin declares some hooks.

One of them is `pytest_collection_finish` which is declared in `PytestBrownieRunner` class. This class is used as plugin constructor during 1 thread test execution. According to [pytest docs](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/reference/reference.html#pytest.hookspec.pytest_collection_finish), this hook is called after all test are collected.

This hook executes following code:

```
if not outcome.get_result() and session.items and not brownie.network.is_connected():
    brownie.network.connect(CONFIG.argv["network"])
```

I believe here it is adding information about your configured network including accounts.

So here is the difference:

When you try to reach `accounts` during tests - code above has been already executed.

However, when you try to reach `accounts` during class definition - no hooks have been executed yet, so there is no information about your network.

May be I am wrong but I assume your issue is related to order of pytest execution stages.

Comment: The accounts should be provided by ganache, which provides 10 accounts.

Launching 'ganache-cli --accounts 10 --hardfork istanbul --gasLimit 12000000 --mnemonic brownie --port 8545'...

Comment: Are you calling this command before whole test run?

Comment: I use "brownie test".

Comment: @LiuzhouZhuo I have updated my answer. Check out explanation above